# How Do You Style Multiple Pages Individually With Css?

Tags: html, css

So I want to style my contact page which has its own file, so when you click on it, it brings you to a whole new page, I already got that I'm Just wondering how do I style that page Inside my style sheets without changing every other page?
i've tried

Inside Html

Inside Css

.stylec {
anything i put in here styles nothing because you cant set the body as a class
}

i havent found any youtube videos for this or anything on google other than
"Yes, It is possible to include one CSS file in another and it can be done multiple times. Also, import multiple CSS files in the main HTML file or in the main CSS file. It can be done by using @import keyword."

I'm Just trying to style my contact page inside my style.css and not styling it inside its html

I just want it all to be inside my styles.css so its neat and clean!

thanks for your time!

Comment: You already said include one css file in another page. That should answer your problem, , and we do it using <link rel="stylesheet" src="some/address/style.css">. And its common practice to keep same theme across multiple pages.

Comment: Singh, the original question states that they " just want it all to be inside my styles.css so its neat and clean!" They are not looking for multiple CSS stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

You should make on stylesheet of CSS and give styles according to the class names.

example:-

```
.first_body
{
background-color: lightblue;
}
.second-body
{
background-color: cyan;
}
```

1st-Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>1st html</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body class="first_body">
    
  </body>
</html>
```

2nd Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>2nd html</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      </head>
      <body class="second_body">
        
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign classes and ids in the html. (You should use an id rather than a class to style the body of a document, since there will only be one  per document.)

For instance in your contact.html (or whatever the contact page's file is called) change your body tag to:

```
<body id="contact-style">
```

Then in your css file you can assign special styling just for that page using...

```
body#contact-style {}
```

You can insert any styles between the curly brackets. To test this, try assigning a background color. If no other elements in your site have a background color, you will see this change right away.

```
body#contact-style {background-color: red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the different pages an `id` attribute on the `body` tag

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="home">
....
</body>
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="contact">
....
</body>
```

In the style sheet that you link to `style.css` you can define styles for all  pages and redefine the styles you want different on the `contact` page

```css
h1 {
font-family: serif;
color: blue;
}

#contact h1 {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: tomato;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay! Your basic HTML document looks like this;

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>

<p class="apple">This is an apple paragraph</p>

<div class="mango">This is a mango paragraph</div>

<h1 id="cat">This is a cat paragraph</h1>

<p class="dog">This is a dog paragraph</p>


</body>
</html>


Note:
Inside the <head> tag is where you import your style.css
Use this tag to import <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
The "href" is used to specify the link of your css file
```

Example of css file:

```
body{
background-color: blue;
}

h1{
color: orange;
}

.apple{
color: green;
}

.mango{
color: yellow;
}

#cat{
color: beige;
}

#dog{
color: white;
}
```